# Front page is occasionally blank, as if no questions had ever been asked

Tags: bug, frontpage

There have been a few times now when I come to the site, and see no questions at all.

Here is a screenshot:

> [image]

Refreshing the page has no effect, nor does switching browsers, nor would (as far as I know) switching computers in any way - looking at the HTML of this blank page, the `<div>` element with id `question-mini-list`, which normally contains the questions, is simply empty.

The problem doesn't last long - 30 seconds at most - so it is difficult to distinguish "fixing" it and going away on its own.

Interestingly, the script that detects *new* questions / activity still functions correctly, so that

[image]

shows up after a while. It's also interesting that the featured tab still indicates its number, but I did not have the presence of mind to check whether the actual featured questions themselves were listed when that tab is switched to.

Comment: That happens when a moderator presses "delete all" by mistake.

Comment: Zev, I'm almost certain that this was asked several times before on the meta site.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/hiding-ignored-tags-hides-all-questions seems related. That time it was a temporary coding issue.